# Is relativization well-defined?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, oracles, relativization

According to BGS theorem [1], there is an oracle $A$ such that $P^A\neq NP^A$.

If the relativization operation $B\mapsto B^A$ was a well-defined function, 
one would expect that from $B^A\neq C^A$ one would be able to conclude that $B\neq C$,
e.g. $P\neq NP$ would follow from BGS. However, $P\neq NP$ is still open.

Does that mean that relativization is not a well-defined function?

If so, do we have any example of two provably different relativizations of the same complexity class?

[1] T. P. Baker, J. Gill, and R. Solovay, "Relativizations of the P =? NP Question"

Comment: Baker-Gill-Solovay shows two oracles: one where P and NP are equal and one where they aren't. That answers your last question.

Comment: @SureshVenkat: if you mean that there are oracles $A,B$ such that $P^A\neq NP^A$ and $P^B=NP^B$ then this result (Ladner's theorem?) is actually the background of my question. I can see why $P^B=NP^B$ does not imply $P=NP$, but I don't see why $P^A\neq NP^A$ does not imply $P\neq NP$.

Comment: @Kaveh would be helpful to point to specific answers. I did a quick scan of the *questions* and didn't see anything.

Comment: PS: the short answer to your question is that a relativization is not an extensional/functional operator on class of problems, even if the notation looks to imply otherwise. There is no general definition of relativization for problem classes,  relativizations are defined for _machine models_ and a single machine model can have several different relativized versions.

Comment: Should this question be on cs.stackexchange.com instead of here? $\;$

Comment: pps: The example you are looking for is IP=PSpace provably but there are relativizations for IP and PSpace which are provably not equal, see [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9934/186). If you want to read more about relativization you can start with Lance Fortnow's survey "[The role of relativization in complexity theory](http://www.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/relative.pdf)", 1994.

Comment: fyi fortnow notes/admits in his abstract that complexity theorists both use and _"misuse"_ relativization.... it seems to be an admittedly gray area of complexity theory _at times_....

Comment: @Suresh, I found these: [Techniques for proving that a sentence relativizes](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/19213/), [Can relativization change the direction of separation?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16268) I remember we had a question which was closer but couldn't find it, it might have got closed as off-topic automatically deleted by the software. Anyway Robin has answered the question quite nicely. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are exactly right. The relativization operation $B\mapsto B^A$ is not well defined. 
P and P<sup>A</sup> are independently defined objects. The names are suggestive, but you cannot formally define P<sup>A</sup> from the set P. (You can define P from P<sup>A</sup> by setting A to be the empty set.)

Think of P<sup>A</sup> as being some kind of generalization of P, which equals P when A is empty, but otherwise may be different. Now if you only know the set P, it is not clear how to generalize this to get P<sup>A</sup>. As an analogy, if I asked you to generalize the real numbers, it's not clear what generalization I'm looking for. Am I thinking of fields, rings, vector spaces, etc.? The reason this happens is that while P is merely a set of languages, P<sup>A</sup> is defined in terms of a machine. This machine has the property that when A is empty it decides exactly the same languages as P. You could come up with some other machine, let's call it Q<sup>A</sup>, which also has the property that when A is empty decides the same languages as P. This does not mean that P<sup>A</sup> = Q<sup>A</sup> for all A. This would be analogous to asserting that if f(0)=g(0), then f and g are the same function.

Perhaps [this post by Terence Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/pnp-relativisation-and-multiple-choice-exams/) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Robin. That's another good answer, and the link to Tao's article is very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

(I assume this question will eventually get migrated to CS.SE, but I am posting my answer to it here on cstheory for now.)

Technically, one doesn't usually think of relativization as an "operator" or "function"; however, I don't see a reason why you couldn't take a *statement* and map the statement to a relativized version of it.

The trick is that, as others have said, relativization isn't really defined over a complexity class; instead, it is defined on the computation model you are using.  Further, what relativizes is the statement, not the classes.  (The notation is a little misleading.)

An example of this is that I could theoretically say that a statement relativizes (or, less likely, doesn't relativize) even if it doesn't refer to a Turing machine at all.  E.g., I could say (truthfully), "1 + 1 = 2" relativizes, because relative to every oracle that could be added to the definition of my universal Turing machine, 1 + 1 = 2 would remain true.

So the short answer is:  Yes, it's well-defined, but not on classes.

Comment: I think for me personally, (and maybe for the OP) the question is: suppose we take the proof that $P^A \ne NP^A$. If $P = NP$, it "appears" to be nonsensical to take the oracle $A$ used in the construction and demonstrate the inequality since the two underlying classes are equal. But clearly it's possible, and so where is my mistake ?

Comment: That's what I was getting at in my answer...I said, you can't relativize over classes, you relativize over statements.  The ability to relativize over P and NP goes away if you cannot relativize over classes individually; the argument doesn't work if I just say "I relativized a statement, now invert the relativization and it should still hold" any more than it's possible to say (using the function f(x) = x^2 as an example) "5^2 is composite" --> "5 is composite."

Comment: There is no general definition of relativization of statements. There is only relativized models of computation. The relativization of P vs. NP presumes that we have fixed the relativized models of P and NP beforehand.