# Is where an oracle B in EXP that $P^B$ $ \ne$ $NP^B$?

Tags: p-vs-np

According to Baker, Gill, Solovey where is an oracle A in EXP, so $P^A$ = $NP^A$. But is there an oracle B in EXP, what $P^B$ $\ne$ $NP^B$?

Comment: Never mind, I was mistaken.

Comment: Yes. Such an oracle $B$ can be constructed by running an exponential number of steps of a polynomial number of Turing machines. So indeed it can be chosen in EXP. A lot of resources on that can be found on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Baker-Gill-Solovay B oracle is itself in EXP.

Comment: http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs468/BGS.pdf

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21663/baker-gill-solovay-pb-ne-npb-relativization-what-class-is-b-in